# Check if the facebook session is valid

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to check if the facebook session is valid or not, it can occure because:

1. The session has expired.
2. User has logged off.
3. User has deleted my facebook application.
4. User no longer exists.

I have this method to check if the user is still logged in:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it returns true even if the user has removed my app from his facebook account.

When I call any facebook request I get the following response from facebook:

```
08-14 12:20:40.671: I/facebookActivity(2322): Result: {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating access token: User 343343434 has not authorized application 45345345.}, isFromCache:false}
```

After that every request I make to facebook I get a different response :

```
08-14 12:21:09.707: I/facebookActivity(2322): Result: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

I can check the JSON for errors and try to create a new Facebook Session, but I want to avoid doing so before making any facebook requests or atleast call it once when the activity starts to check if the session is valid.

Is there a normal way to check whether a session is valid?

Comment: I think that the new facebook sdk is good, but it lacks documentation and some basic methods,well defined documentation, and normal tutorial which which is not directed to fragments.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question but I would suggest that if you use a `if (condition) return true else return false` replace it with `return condition`. So in your case, just use `return (session!=null && session.isOpened());`

Comment: @IvoBeckers it is only semantics and the condition would be much longer if there was one to check if the session is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a session from cached information (normally done automatically for you), there's no server requests made to Facebook, which is why the Session object itself has no idea whether it's still valid or not.

The only way to know that an access token has been invalidated (for any reason) is to make a graph request. You can either make a graph request every time you open a new session (to /me or even /me/permissions), or you can have your app proceed as normal, and perform the error handling steps outlined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) when an error occurs (note that a session/access token can become invalid at any time - even in the middle of running your app - so you should have proper error handling regardless).

Comment: couldn't you use session.getExpirationDate().getTime() <  System.currentTimeMillis() to determine if the session is still valid?

Comment: That is only one of the many reasons a session could become invalid (and the SDK already checks that for you). There are many other ways (like user changing their password, user deactivating their FB account, etc) that a session can become invalid, and there's no way to tell from the client side until you get an explicit error from the server.